# Properly update the source Option in bootstrap-typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, underscore.js, typeahead

In the following [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BwDmM/70/), after inserting "Alaska" value, 
the source is updated so that the autocomplete is not showing again Alaska value.

```
var newSource = this.source
                    .slice(0,pos)
                    .concat(this.source.slice(pos+1));
this.source = newSource;
```

Anyway if I remove Alaska from the textarea, the value `Alaska` should be displayed again in the source.
Any hints how to restore the source data if the user delete the data from the textarea?

My idea is to access the options `source option from

```
$('.typeahead').on('change', function () { })
```

Any hints?

P.S.:
I am using jquery and underscore

Answer (score 2):

You should probably rather change your `matcher` function in order to test over the already selected states :

```
var tabPresentStates = this.query.split(','),
    nbPresentStates = tabPresentStates.length;
for(var iState = 0; iState < nbPresentStates; iState++) {
   if(item === tabPresentStates[iState].trim())
       return false;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/DCUyT/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the source you can use the sorter to exclude the values you've already selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/BwDmM/71/

*P.S. I'll probably include your code in next version of Jasny's extended Bootstrap http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap :)*

```
!function(source) {
    function extractor(query) {
        var result = /([^,]+)$/.exec(query);
        if(result && result[1])
            return result[1].trim();
        return '';
    }

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: source,
        updater: function(item) {
            return this.$element.val().replace(/[^,]*$/,'')+item+',';
        },
        matcher: function (item) {
          var tquery = extractor(this.query);
          if(!tquery) return false;
          return ~item.toLowerCase().indexOf(tquery)
        },
        highlighter: function (item) {

          var query = extractor(this.query).replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
          return item.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
            return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>'
          })
        },
        sorter: function(items) {
          var beginswith = []
            , caseSensitive = []
            , caseInsensitive = []
            , existing = $.each(this.$element.val().split(','), function(i, val) { return val.trim() })
            , item

          while (item = items.shift()) {
            if ($.inArray(item, existing) >= 0) continue;

            if (!item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase())) beginswith.push(item)
            else if (~item.indexOf(this.query)) caseSensitive.push(item)
            else caseInsensitive.push(item)
          }

          return beginswith.concat(caseSensitive, caseInsensitive)              
        }
    });

}(["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska","Nevada","New Hampshire","New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Dakota","North Carolina","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania","Rhode Island","South Carolina","South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"]);
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you use `sorter` instead of `matcher`? I think that it is dedicated to another kind of treatment, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @SamuelCaillerie's approach to use `matcher` - this is just using your extractor function. So:

```
    updater: function(item) {
        return this.$element.val().replace(/[^,]*$/,'')+item+',';
    },
    matcher: function (item) {
      var previouslySelected = (this.query.indexOf(item) != -1); 
      var tquery = (previouslySelected ? "" : extractor(this.query));
      if(!tquery) return false;
      return ~item.toLowerCase().indexOf(tquery)
    },
```